# Understanding the attractive fixed point of Mobius transformation

Tags: complex-analysis, hyperbolic-geometry, mobius-transformation

Book: An introduction to Teichmuller Space by Imayoshi & Taniguchi.
Let $\gamma$ be a Mobius transformation on $\Bbb C$ such that $\Bbb H\to\Bbb H$ (Automorphism of upper half plane). Suppose
$$\gamma(z) = {az+b\over cz+d},\quad ad-bc =1,c>0$$
such that $1$ is the attractive fixed point of $\gamma$, i.e., we can conjugate $\gamma$ in $\mathrm{Aut}(\Bbb H)$ so that it becomes a map $z\mapsto \lambda z$ such that $\Bbb R\ni\lambda \neq 0,1$ and if $0<\lambda<1$ then $0$ in this new map corresponds to $1$ in the original map and if $\lambda>1$ then $\infty$ in this new map corresponds to $1$in the original map (if I understand the definition correctly). Now the book say that this 'attractive' condition is equivalent to the followings:
$$a+b= c+d,\quad 0<-{b\over c}<1.$$
The first condition says $1$ is a fixed point of $\gamma$. I think the second condition is saying some attractiveness of $\gamma$ at $1$ but I don't understand why. So far I found that $-{b\over c}$ is another fixed point $\gamma$.

Using these two conditions, books concludes $\gamma(\infty) = a/c>0$ and $a+d>0$ because the middle-point $(a-d)/(2c)$ of two fixed points of $\gamma_2$ has a value less than $\gamma_2(\infty)$. I don't understand the reasoning. Could you explain? I think I don't understand the concept of *attractive* and *repelling* (fixed) points.

[image: .]

Comment: one way is to compute the derivative of $\gamma$ at $z=1$; that fixed point is attractive iff the $|\gamma'(z=1)|<1$

Comment: @user8268 Then the condition is written in terms of $c$ and $d$ not with $b$.

Comment: If $\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ with $ad-bc=1,c>0$ has attractive fixed point $1$, this does not imply the other fixed point $-b/c$ is in $(0,1)$. For example the transformation with attractive fixed point $1$ and repelling fixed point $-1/2$ and factor $\lambda=1/2$ is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{18}}[\begin{smallmatrix}4&2\\15\end{smallmatrix}]$. Also you never define $\gamma_2$ in your question. The screenshot appears to cover generic definitions we can find anywhere instead of the actual text you're speaking about.